# json describing a boolean

Tags: c#, javascript, json

I have a field in a server-side object model that's a boolean. I'm writing a custom json converter and I'm wondering how best encode this for json. Should I leave it as a boolean or should I convert `true` to `1` and `false` to `0`.

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you writing a custom JSON converter?

Comment: Because some properties are not meant to be visible to the client.

Comment: I'm not understanding why you'd want to describe a boolean as anything but a boolean, unless you're using a language that doesn't support that type.

Comment: To save space in the json string; apparently it's not such a good idea.

Comment: Alright, but then it's not about how to represent a boolean. It's about saving space. If you want to save space, then that's something you need to decide. You also need to consider whether it will make sense to the targeted languages.

Comment: ...FYI, JavaScript's `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` accept a "reviver/replacer" function that let you mutate the data during the processing. Perhaps your server-side language offers the same thing?

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I'll just leave it as a boolean. For now I'm the only developer on my app but it seems it'll be easier than later explaining that booleans are converted to 0/1. I upvoted everyone, thanks for your feedback.

Comment: That's definitely the safe route. Plus, if you're gzipping the files, there's a good chance that it'll make little difference anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer using the true/false keywords in my JSON, but 1/0 will still work. Is your question on how to write the code to create this JSON object?  It depends on how you are implementing the converter.  What have you got so far?

Answer (score 2):

As per the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) (§2.1), booleans are either `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no defined best way. It depends on you (who uses this).

Persobally I think, If you are representing boolean, Use **`True` / `False`** , instead of 1 /0. That is more readable ( for future developers who is going to maintain this code / When you look at this code after few months).

Comment: To add to this, using `True/False` may make your code more robust in the future. Whatever language you use now to interpret the JSON (probably JavaScript) will treat 1 as truthy and 0 as false, but what if you expose this JSON as part of an API later? Someone may reach out to your service, parse the JSON and create an Int/Number/Whatever strongly-typed, truthy object for 0, then have to work around this limitation in an illogical way. Even if there are no plans to ever do this, it's usually beneficial to reduce the semantic gap between what you want and what you mean to as little as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `true` and `false` as it makes it more clear that the values are boolean.